# Which is best software design for heavy query based app

Tags: design, design-patterns, architecture, database, linq

I am in charge of design an application (.NET) that has these features:

- It´s a desktop app (maybe in the future will be web-based)
- It´s  functionality is  to provide users analyzed data retrieved from database.
  It is done by performing heavy queries generating , graphs and grid-tables to show the information.  Users analyze the data to make decisions. The data is stored in relational tables and needs to be treated before being shown. The information is related to statistics, accounting, etc
- Queries are not too much complicated. Multiple Joins with GroupBy,Sum and other calculations will be the worst situation.
- Database will be migrated from Oracle => SQL Server
- The model is related to assembling cars. It stores information about the items that compose a car (price, model, etc). Also stores info about providers, disccounts.
- Domain logic will be able to calculate budgets to some specific cars in one click, perfoming a lot of queries and calculations.

My doubts/questions are:

A) I want to put all the logic inside the code, avoiding the use of stored procedures in the database. I don't like he fact they can not get tested with "generic code" (which will work despite the db engine) and their appearance of being a black-box outputting data. Also i dont want , changes of database engine affects the app too much. I am right? 
I prefer to have them implemented in LINQ or other approach you think could fit. Do you see some disadvantage on that? Probably memory issues? ( The managed data contains thousands of records with dozens of tables)

B) The queries logic should go in the domain layer. Which will be a good pattern/approach to place them in a scalable way? The number of queries will increase during app maintenance.

C) Do you know a nice approach to unit test the queries in LINQ? Fake data, moqs, etc? Some advice on that?

Comment: I think we need a bit more details : the query will obvisouly run against thousands of records, but what do the user get ? A grid with rows that you can load only partially and get the rest on the fly ? A report generated with all the data ? And does the complexity of the requests is high enough to eventually rely only on raw SQL or are you sure LINQ and not too complex queries will do the job ?

Comment: No answer to your question, but it is wrong that you can't test stored procedures. For example, in some companies their ETL resides mostly inside the database and is done with stored procedures. You can bet they are tested as well. Just directly on the database with SQL code (for example).

Comment: It is in fact possible to [unit test stored procedures in SQL Server](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1GGRV_enFR751__752&ei=bBz8Wpb0OIyCgAaA5KjADw&q=unit+test+SSDT+stored+procedures&oq=unit+test+SSDT+stored+procedures&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i160k1.3779.6977.0.7089.26.26.0.0.0.0.177.2247.14j8.22.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..4.19.1880...0i22i30k1j33i21k1.0.Y34KlXzi31w)

Comment: But that aside, I suspect the bottleneck will be getting the data over to the mid tier or wherever you're going to be doing your number crunching.

Comment: Few users doing heavy queries to a grid does not sound like a big problem. I would try to make a naive implementation and make certain the grid supports paging. It also sounds like you can read uncomitted. I would also not use stored procedures, and my personal experience is that linq to entities is faster in .net core than 4.6

Comment: @Walfrat I would prefer to use LINQ because the logic resides in the code, so I make it independent from database changes (for example oracle to sql server)  .The problem is that maybe the joins & data its big enough to produce perfomance issues

Comment: And there is PLINQ of course...

Comment: @RobbieDee i don´t want to redevelop the business rules each time i change the database engine. So i think stored procedures are not the best choice

Comment: @Walfrat queries are not too much complicated, just summarize the data, group by date(month,year) . Query items wih some characteristics. Multiple Joins are needed across multiple tables, that will be the worst scenario

Comment: @Badulake Fair enough - it would certainly help with portability...

Answer (score 1):

For any kind of reporting you should create a data warehouse with cubes and like and query that rather than the underlying transactional databases.

Often these data warehouses will come with their own reporting tools, it can often be best just to use those rather than develop a system on top of them.

However, If you need to push those reports out to external customers then you will want to restrict access. In this case you application can run the MDX (or alternate tech) query against the cue and display the report in a customer charting component or grid.

In either case you are reducing the required logic by using a data warehouse which will flatten the data first, and keeping that logic in the form of a query rather than in code.

Comment: the database is not only for reporting. As an example:  the database will store wich pieces compose a CAR . Each model of car will have their own set of pieces, each one with its price, provider, etc etc. We want to query that data for  generating budgets with one click. The budgets should query price of each item, also apply some disccounts based on some calculations of other facts like driver experience, accidents, relations with providers  etc (huge etc). Do you think that fits a data wharehouse?

Comment: hmm it could do "budget" is an odd word to use if you mean "the cost of a single car assembled from these parts"

Comment: yes , you are right with the meaning of budget

Comment: if you mean "the average cost of cars by model calculated by summing the part cost from various suppliers, broken down per month" then yes definitely

Comment: No, we want the budget to be generated  for a new car driver with the actual data (not historical, or reports, just the active data today) . Reporting is another piece of the app. But main work will be to analize and provide an instant budget

Comment: if im buying a car and selecting upgrades, say "alloy wheels" then that's a price not a budget, how does it fit with "performing heavy queries generating , graphs and grid-tables to show the information"

Comment: each car is composed by thousands of pieces. Each piece is involved in some kind of processes which applies disccounts. All the info is stored in the database. Imagine : piece XXX01 have a disccount because there is an active promotion with the provider until 30-may-2018. Maybe the queries are not as heavy as you are thinking. Just thousands of records should be considered. When yopu are composing the car you will get a graph and a grid with the data of your Car, disccounts applied. logistic cost, etc

Comment: sounds like a pricing engine. can be pretty heavy work, if you need to work out combination discounts on 1000s of items. not datawarehouse or sql you need to split it into worker jobs

Comment: Can you give more light over it? What do you mean by worker jobs?

Comment: you are right, best name is a  is a "pricing engine" If you give me an answer explaining which approach you will  take (software desing, where to put the workers, etc) in that pricing engine i will give you "correct answer" many thanks dude